# How do I apply date formatting and add attributes to a textbox in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my application, I want all dates to display in the MM/DD/YYYY format and I also want the text box to be limited to 10 characters and have a certain class applied to it.

To that end, I made a custom editor template for Date that looks like this:

```
@ModelType System.Nullable(Of DateTime)

@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(d) d, New With {.class="polkDate", .maxlength="10"})
```

Then in my view I just can just call `@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.someDate)` and this works pretty well. However, because I'm using `TextBoxFor`, it doesn't respect the `DisplayFormat` attribute that's applied to my model class (i.e. it's spitting out the time as well instead of formatting the date).

I would love to use `EditorFor` so that it would respect the formatting that I want, but you can't add attributes like class and maxlength. I also tried just using the plain old `TextBox` helper, but I don't know how to make it generate the correct ID so that model binding still works.

Anybody know a way to make this happen? I don't feel like what I want to do here is too outlandish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to do the trick:

```
@ModelType Date

@If Date.MinValue.Equals(Model) Then
    @Html.TextBox("", Nothing, New With {.class="polkDate", .maxlength="10"})
Else
    @Html.TextBox("", Model.ToShortDateString(), New With {.class="polkDate", .maxlength="10"})
End If
```

Looks like the framework automatically assigns the ID and name fields of the html input tag so everything works properly.